# Network Graph in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph, tidygraph

I want to build a network diagram from a dataframe that I have, but I am having troubles.

This is what the dataframe looks like.

| Shop | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | 34 |
| S1 | 12 |
| S2 | 11 |
| S2 | 34 |
| S3 | 34 |
| S4 | 50 |

For example, S1 should be connected to S2 and S3 since they have the same manager and so on. Also, is it possible to set the size of the dot based on the number of managers a shop has?

I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` + `tcrossprod` + `table`

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.dist(tcrossprod(table(df))))
```

and `plot(g)` shows the network like below

[image]

---

Another way is `bipartite.projection`

```
df %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = names(V(.)) %in% df$Shop) %>%
  bipartite.projection() %>%
  pluck(2) %>%
  plot()
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Shop = c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S3", "S4"), 
    Manager = c(34L, 12L, 11L, 34L, 34L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use the `bipartite_projection` function (I haven't tried, but the operation the OP is asking for is bipartite projection).

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, exactly. I added the `bipartite.projection` option.